# stock quantity woocommorce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock

i have a problem with my stock display.
our current code, if the number of "variant products" is more than 5, it does not show stock information. we want to apply it also for "simple products". How should we revise our code?

```
function get_variation_stock_status( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        if ( $variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ) {
            $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $variation['variation_id'] );

            // if the stock of the product is greater than 20 it returns
            if ( $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity() > 5 ) {
                return '';
            }
            
            $stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
            break;
        }
    }
   return $stock_qty == 0 ? ' - ' . __(pll__('Stokta Yok'), 'mytheme-hello') : ' - ' . $stock_qty . '  ' .  __(pll__('adet Stokta'), 'mytheme-hello');
}
```

I would be very happy if you can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check product type using `is_type()`. check the below code.

```
function get_variation_stock_status( $product, $name, $term_slug ){

    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {

        // if the stock of the product is greater than 20 it returns
        if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 5 ) {
            return '';
        }

        $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        
        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){

            if ( $variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ) {

                $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $variation['variation_id'] );

                // if the stock of the product is greater than 20 it returns
                if ( $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity() > 5 ) {
                    return '';
                }
                
                $stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
                break;
            }

        }
        
    }
    
    return $stock_qty == 0 ? ' - ' . __(pll__('Stokta Yok'), 'mytheme-hello') : ' - ' . $stock_qty . '  ' .  __(pll__('adet Stokta'), 'mytheme-hello');
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but nothing changed.